Why isn't "principix" the feminine of "princeps"?
What's the feminine version of princeps? Why isn't it "principix" (along the lines of auctor → auctrix, bellator → bellatrix, etc.)?
Related question: "Are there feminine and neuter versions of 'professor'"?

Wiktionary also says that noun princeps can be used in both masculine and feminine gender.

There is no suffix -ix in words auctrix and bellatrix. -tor and -trīx are actual suffixes in those words which you mentioned.

@Arfrever Adding to the confusion…

@Arfrever I don't understand. Can you please explain?

@Geremia Which part needs more explanation?

I for one think this is an excellent question. the answer is: there is no word principix  because there is no word principor. There is a word principissa derived from masculine princeps just like there is a word prophetissa derived from masculine propheta.

@Figulus I have not heard about any suffix -ix in Latin. Latin has suffix -or (from PIE -ōs), but it is used to create action nouns or result nouns, and is unrelated to suffix -tor (from PIE -tōr) used to create agent nouns.

E.g. amā- + -or → ‎amor "love"; amā- + -tor → amātor "male lover"; amā- + -trīx → amātrīx "female lover"; can- + -or → canor "song"; can- + -tor → cantor "male singer"; can- + -trīx → cantrīx "female singer".

@Figulus Coincidentally, deponent verb prīncipor "to rule (over)" happens to exist :) . Agent nouns derived from this verb would be prīncipātor and prīncipātrīx.

You can't mix and match elements as you please.
The female agent ending is -trix while the other two genders have -tor and -trum.
There's an earlier question on these agent nouns for those who want details.
This means that there's no independent -ix that you could stick to words and make them feminine.
A silly comparison to English:
Given the pairs 'man' & 'woman' and 'policeman' & 'policewoman', you might be led to thinking that you can use '-wo-' to make nouns feminine.
But a female dog can't be called a *'dwoog'.
There is a grammar to how you can put components together and derive new words.
See e.g. A&G on deriving nouns in Latin.
The suffix -trix comes in one piece and is used to denote female agents.
You can't separate a piece out of it nor can you use it for women that are not agents.
I strongly recommend that you study the grammar of your choice on Latin derivation rules to get a firmer grip of the toolbox available.
Use the rules, don't improvise.
Principissa is an existing word for a princess.
It is very different from *principix — you can't just change the ends of Latin words and hope to have no effect.
An even if the derivation of one seems obscure or the invalidity of the derivation of the other one unconvincing, the fact that one is attested but the other one is not speaks volumes.
Use the proper one.
The suffix -issa appears to be a medieval one used to make titles feminine: principissa, abbatissa, ducissa.
It seems that principissa is not a valid derivation within classical Latin.
In classical Latin there seems to be no unambiguous one-word translation for "princess", so you just have to describe it as filia regis or similar.

Du Cange does give "Principissa, Regina, vel Principis uxor" under princeps. Principissa seems similar to "principix".

@Geremia I had indeed meant to add a note that principissa is indeed probably the best word for "princess". But I vehemently disagree that principissa and *principix are similar. The latter strikes me as an invalid derivation, and most importantly it is not an attested word.

Are there other "-issa" derivations?

@Geremia The word principissa is not classical, and it is indeed not a valid derivation within the Latin of the Romans. It is from later Latin, with the suffix -issa borrowed from Greek. Several medieval titles appear to use it for feminine versions, like abbatissa and ducissa. I'll edit to add a note.

And cometissa.
